# Как отслеживать события в своем классе происходящие в отдельном классе Listener?

Tags: java, android, listener

У меня есть наследник `Service` и наследник `BroadcastReceiver`.

Как в `Service` в реальном времени отлавливать событие которые происходят в BroadcastReceiver чтобы реагировать на них? Надо слушатель на на слушателя :)

В голову приходит только thread с циклом по времени в `Service` который будет периодически проверять состояния в `BroadcastReceiver` но тогда это же можно делать и без `BroadcastReceiver`. Или может надо создать какой-то общий интерфейс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте `intent` (в который сложили необходимые данные) из `BroadcastReceiver` в `service` и разбирайте/обрабатывайте в `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Спасибо. Хорошая мысль.

Comment: Хм...я тут поковырялся... `onStartCommand()` запускается при старте `service` и принять интент может только при старте. А если у меня сервис постоянно запущен и занимается наблюдением за `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: `return START_STICKY` попробуйте в `onStartCommand()`

Comment: И что это даст? Если сервис будет убит то система его перезапустит...Это конечно хороше. Но сервис должен постоянно реагировать на новые оповещения от `BroadcastReceiver` не перезапускаясь при этом.

Comment: `onStartCommand()` вызывается для каждого интента, не важно был уже запущен сервис или нет

Comment: Да, ребята, вы правы! Спасибо. Все работает. Разобрался.